# Problem hiding files & folders in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I would like to configure Tortoise's global ignore patterns to hide the folder "scripts/shavrir/database" and everything under it, including subfolders. For this, I added to the global ignore patterns this pattern:

```
"scripts/shavrir/database/*.*"
```

This has no effect, neither of files directly in said folder or in its sub-folders.

I don't want to use .svnignore file because I'd like to get the effect on all branches. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just totally wild guesses, but can you try 1.) adding a slash to the front `/scripts....`  and 2.) just use `*` instead of `*.*`?

Comment: Ignore patters only match on a single level, so you would have to add 'database' if you want to apply it globally. But I would recommend applying it on just the parent folder

Comment: Pekka - I tried several varients, didn't work. Jamie's answer did it, and there's also a UI shortcut to do this from the "commit" window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global ignore list does not use paths. For this, you want to use the svn:ignore property, which is simple if you're using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `svn:ignore` property to this value

```
database
```

on all of your

```
scripts/shavrir
```

folders.  You’ll only have to do it once, because from then on when you create a branch (which is a copy), it will copy the properties of this folder as well.